# How do I activate the Interactive Console on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1780618) and I'd like to use the Interactive console you get on the local dev server (http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin) on the cloud server to make sure a query is working as I expect.

I read before you can enable it - but how is it done?

Comment: why don't Google document their products properly? I'm glad this question is answered here but would also like to read it "from the horse's mouth". If anyone can point to some Google documentation about this I'd be glad (as would others searching for this question).

Comment: now I feel silly. It's documented here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Referring_to_the_Python_Library_Directory

Comment: corrected URL: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Referring_to_the_Python_library_directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following to your app.yaml, before any .* handler:

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/admin
  login: admin
```

Another option for your use-case is to enable remote_api, then use the `remote_api_shell.py` tool included with the SDK, allowing you to test things from a local Python shell.

Answer (score 27):

Nick's answer doesn't work anymore when using the "threadsafe" option. Instead, you have to use:

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin
```

Comment: Does anyone know what the url should be? I tried myapp.appspot.com/admin/interactive but I am getting a 404.

Comment: @Zaffiro Maybe you defined the handler after the handler for '/' in app.yaml?

Comment: The full path is /admin/console/interactive