# Google App Engine & Django Sandbox: Shell and Web seem to be using different datastores?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to both Django and Google App Engine, and am using a sandbox in OSX10.6 with the GoogleAppEngineLauncher. I've got a basic "bookstore" application running from the tutorial in the OReilly "Programming Google App Engine" book.

Here's the bug: If I add a new object to the datastore through the web interface, then it's readable through the web interface, but does not appear to exist if I query the datastore through the shell. Vice versa: If I add an object in the shell, then I can read it from the shell, but it doesn't appear in the web interface.

A related curio: All data vanishes from both datastores when I reboot my computer.

Any thoughts or theories would be welcome. Thanks!

=T=

Comment: Are you using anything to help with django?  Like google-app-engine-django, django-nonrel, app-engine-patch, or something else?  Each has a way to specify the datastore file location.

Comment: i'm using google-app-engine-django. Don't know what those other things are.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the remote API shell and point it at the instance you're running on your machine, you should get the same datastore.  It's unclear how you're accessing your app via "the shell", but it seems that you're creating a second instance to do so.

The data vanishes from the datastore when you reboot your machine because by default the datastore file is created in /tmp; you can specify another location (one that the system doesn't clean for you on reboot) for it when you run dev_appserver.py.

Comment: i'm accessing the shell by running "python manage.py shell" in my app's home dir

Comment: How are you running the server?  I believe "python manage.py runserver" should get you the same datastore as using manage.py shell, whereas running dev_appserver.py manually will get you a different datastore.  This may also depend on any helpers/patches you're using, however.

Comment: I've been running the server via the GoogleAppEngineLauncher app. I'll try running it from command line instead and making sure both it and my shell are pointing at the same datastore.

Comment: How do I create a new datastore? When I point dev_appserver at an empty file or directory, it throws errors.

Comment: I was able to hack this by copying the datastore from /tmp into another directory and then specifying the new location when I run appserver or shell. That seems to have solved the problem!

Comment: Actually google-app-engine-django's manage.py doesn't have a flag I can see to allow to specify an alternate datastore path...

Comment: Looks like this is an outstanding feature request for the gae django helper: http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=103

Answer (score 0):

That's right, `python manage.py` will get you to another instance of the app (and another datastore) than the Launcher. If you'd like a command-line interface with your application, see [How do I activate the Interactive Console on App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782906/how-do-i-activate-the-interactive-console-on-app-engine), or run the dev server solely from `python manage.py runserver` rather than the Launcher and continue to use `manage.py shell`.

I've been bitten by the same datastore deletion. App Engine, for some reason, needs to close shop carefully -- you have to hit "stop" (or hit ctrl-c if running from the dev_appserver.py command, typically on linux) to have the datastore save properly to disk. If you turn off the computer before properly closing out, the datastore will be deleted.