# GAE - Online admin console

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there some way I can run custom python code on my google appengine app online? Is there a python console somewhere that I can use? I've seen vague references here and there, but nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782906/how-do-i-activate-the-interactive-console-on-app-engine) on how to enable the interactive console (that you can use on the local dev appserver) on your deployed application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote shell, that is on your app engine sdk.
For example
~/bin/google_appengine/remote_api_shell.py -s your-app-identifier.appspot.com s~your-app-identifier

When you are inside the shell, you will have the db module enabled. in order to use your models, you will have to import them.