# Create entity using datastore viewer Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to create an entity in my datastore from the admin console on google app engine.

To do this, I read I must clicked on the tab "create" in the datastore viewer BUT I don't have this link.
I have just the "query" tab and as I have no data, nothing appears.

How can I create an entity from the admin console on google app engine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

App Engine will only let you create new entities for a Kind that has already been defined. If you haven't ever saved anything to the datastore, your datastore is a blank slate, and you won't be able to query or create in it.

If you don't want to deploy code in order to write your first entities to the datastore, you can enable the [interactive console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782906/how-do-i-activate-the-interactive-console-on-app-engine) in production, and write code that generates a model, populates, and saves it. Once you've done that, your Create link should appear.

Comment: Also note that even with this approach, the Create tab is quite limited: you can't add properties that aren't already used in the datastore, and you can't create certain types of properties (e.g. text and blob).  What are you trying to do that you don't want to write some code to enter data?

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions section maybe you only have the Viewer role which doesn't allow you to create entities.

BTW, the create link looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm the owner of the application. I have the admin permissions normaly

Comment: Viewer is also defined as admin but with less privileges

Comment: So normaly I should see this link ? Why I don't see it ?