# Preloading Entities in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just deployed a site on GAE which requires me to stage some data for dropdown fields (i.e. us states, status, etc.).

In development, I have created an entity for each type of data (US State entity for example) and was able to preload the data using the interactive console by creating the entity and then calling the put() method.

Now that the application is deployed I don’t know of a way to preload this data. How would you recommend doing this in a deployed instance?

I am using SDK version 1.7.0, python 2.7, High Replication Datastore (HRD), and memcache when data is retrieved.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically, you may use the interactive console in production. Check out [How do I activate the Interactive Console on App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782906/how-do-i-activate-the-interactive-console-on-app-engine)

You may also create a temporary request handler that'll do the job, deploy it (e.g. as a different version of the app to make it easy to delete) and launch the respective URL in your browser.

Comment: Thanks Bugs.. I tried activating the admin but myapp.appspot.com/admin/interactive is not working for me. Is the url correct?

Comment: Try myapp.appspot.com/admin/console/interactive

Comment: yeah that worked. I put the admin handler after - url: /.*.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bulkloader to upload your entities to your deployed version. See the doc [Uploading and Downloading Data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) for details and examples.