# How to debug GAE python, gql and datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have been struggling to find ways to debug some python scripts and gql datastore queries in GAE using textmate.

For the gql queries, can we print the queries to see what's in the database? (like php print_r function).

For the .py files, anyway we can log it? I tried using logging module. `logging.info` or `logging.debug` doesn't seem to return anything in the browser or the GAE `console.log`. Where does it suppose to return the output?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: "The development server prints logging output to the console. If you are using the Launcher, you can open a window of development server output by clicking the Logs button."

Comment: For an example to use the logging module see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/logging)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Console](http://con.appspot.com/console/help/about) which will allow you to run Python commands directly in production. [Here is a question relating to that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782906/how-do-i-activate-the-interactive-console-on-app-engine) The **interactive** console may help debug those queries a bit faster.

logging.debug **does** work, but it logs to the log system on your app engine admin panel. Go to appengine.google.com, select your application then click on "logs". Then select "Logs with minimum severity: Debug" and you'll see your logging info.

Answer (score 0):

You can always stick to good old Python built-in [pdb symbolic debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). It works if `dev_appserver.py` is run from command line.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Debugging_with_PDB